# What is up with Yosef calling Yaakov אבי in the singular when talking to his brothers

Tags: parshanut-torah-comment

After revealing himself to his brothers Yosef consistently refers to Yaakov as "my father"—not "our father" (Bereishis 45:3,9,13).

Is he doing it consciously to rub it in their faces basically telling them that I'm the favored son and Yaakov is only "my father" in some sense (Yosef also being the main wife Rachel's son) or is it perhaps merely the conventional biblical style of speech?

Comment: [This Tur HaAroch](https://www.sefaria.org/Tur_HaArokh%2C_Genesis.45.3.1?lang=bi) at least holds the possibility that he was trying to draw them closer (and the translator explains that it is because he switched from second person to first person vs 43:27). It doesn't answer why first person is better than inclusive plural for this etc

Comment: Yosef already knew Yaakov was alive. He was wondering how he'd managed to survive the pain and offering solace with the news of his success. Maybe that's why it's in singular, because he was addressing his father's attachment to him.

Comment: Thank you chevrah for responding. Shmosel, that is a nice idea and I believe R O Seforno explains along those lines in pasuk 3. I suppose it can work for pasuk 9 as well but gets more difficult for 13, unless you say that once he's referred to him like that already he's gonna keep it uniform for that convo.